# Manipulating .hdr image file (MRI)

Tags: python-2.7

I have a .hdr file, this contains data for an image taken from an MRI scan.

Now I need to know how to manipulate these types of files to do image processing on them using python(things like 3d median filtering, dividing one image by another).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more light-weight solution is to use the `nibabel` library:

http://nipy.org/nibabel/

As you can see it shares a lot of features (as well as developers...) with nipy, but it is pure python and really only meant to do neuroimaging data format I/O

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution: you can make use of the nipy module. This way you use it to load the .hdr file (assuming the .img file is in the same path), then you can save this as a different file, specifically .nii, and this combines them. This way, you can have numpy treat this as an ndarray and voila, image manipulation is now possible! (Just make sure to load the data from the image so you can treat it as a numpy array) See [here](http://nipy.org/)

Comment: I am struck with the same problem. Can you give me a sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the nibabel library in python for loading the .hdr and .img images in python.
Here's the link - https://nipy.org/nibabel/reference/nibabel.html#module-nibabel

To load the .hdr and .img images, use the following piece of code.

```
import nibabel as nb
img = nb.load("file.img")
hdr = nb.load("file.hdr")
```

You can plot the .img file using matplotlib and just print the contents of 'hdr' to inspect the metadata.

Also, it must be noted that 'img' is also a bumpy memory map file and you can manipulate it as you would do to a ndarray.